# I think my hql is right,why I can`t run it?

Tags: hive, hiveql

```
insert into table dws_new_mid_day select ud.mid_id,ud.user_id,ud.version_code,ud.version_name,ud.lang,ud.source,ud.os,ud.area,ud.model,ud.brand,ud.sdk_version,ud.gmail,ud.height_width,ud.app_time,ud.network,ud.lng,ud.lat,'2020-09-24' from dws_uv_detail_day ud left join dws_new_mid_day nm on ud.mid_id=nm.mid_id where ud.dt='2020-09-24' and nm.mid_id is null;
```

the error is this:

```
FAILED: SemanticException 1:18 Need to specify partition columns because the destination table is partitioned. Error encountered near token 'dws_new_mid_day'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify partition column whilst inserting into a partitioned table (`dws_new_mid_day` in your case). Try something like this instead:

**Static Partition:**

```
INSERT INTO TABLE dws_new_mid_day PARTITION (dt = '2020-09-24')
SELECT ud.mid_id,
       ud.user_id,
       ud.version_code,
       ud.version_name,
       ud.lang,
       ud.source,
       ud.os,
       ud.area,
       ud.model,
       ud.brand,
       ud.sdk_version,
       ud.gmail,
       ud.height_width,
       ud.app_time,
       ud.network,
       ud.lng,
       ud.lat
FROM dws_uv_detail_day ud
LEFT JOIN dws_new_mid_day nm ON ud.mid_id=nm.mid_id
WHERE ud.dt='2020-09-24'
  AND nm.mid_id IS NULL;
```

**Dynamic Partition:**

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;  
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

INSERT INTO TABLE dws_new_mid_day PARTITION (dt)
SELECT ud.mid_id,
       ud.user_id,
       ud.version_code,
       ud.version_name,
       ud.lang,
       ud.source,
       ud.os,
       ud.area,
       ud.model,
       ud.brand,
       ud.sdk_version,
       ud.gmail,
       ud.height_width,
       ud.app_time,
       ud.network,
       ud.lng,
       ud.lat,
       ud.dt as dt
FROM dws_uv_detail_day ud
LEFT JOIN dws_new_mid_day nm ON ud.mid_id=nm.mid_id
WHERE ud.dt='2020-09-24'
  AND nm.mid_id IS NULL;
```

Remember, you've to change the partition column name. I just kept it as "dt" for demonstration.

Comment: thank you for your help,I forget it it`s a partition table....